# Expire S3 Pre Signed URL soon after the file is downloaded

Tags: amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

Is it possible to make the Pre-Signed URL expire soon after the file is downloaded? 
I have a scenario where I want the URL to be accessed for 1 time only. Opening the URL again should not download the file?

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible.

A pre-signed URL is generated with an Expiry time. There is **no limit** on the number of times that the URL can be accessed within the expiry period.

You would need to serve the file through your application to achieve this functionality, rather than serving from Amazon S3.

Answer (score 4):

There is really no way to tell S3 to allow access to a link only once. 
What you can do is let a link be used until a specified time in the future.

So if you set the expiry of the link to a short time (few minutes) it means they don't have time to share the link. The expiration time can be a few seconds too just long enough for the browser to get the redirection request and follow it.

Have a look at the documentation on how to create these URLs [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)

Comment: What if the file is big? Does the signed url have to be valid until the download is done? Or once the connection is made it is doesn't matter if the url expires?

Comment: Any downloads started before expiry will work. But some multi part downloaders that may not be able to request for new segments after expiration. Also pause and resume won’t work once expired